# What's 'i' for in Angular CLI command: 'ng g i student'?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am learning about **activatedRoute** following this article:
*[Angular 13 ActivatedRoute Route Tutorial with Example](https://www.positronx.io/understand-angular-7-activatedroute-route-and-its-usage/)*

I'm confused about this part:

> Run the following command to generate student interface class for setting up data types.
>
> ```bash
> ng g i student
> ```
>
> Afterwards, go to `student.ts` file and add the following code into it.

I get that `g` is for `generate`; but what is the `i` for? Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: You can always use the CLI help to find this type of thing out. `ng g i --help` provide a lot of information.

Answer (score 3):

`ng g i student` will be creating an interface.`i` stands for interface. This command is equivalent to `ng generate interface student`.

So an interface student will be generated after running the command `ng g i student`.

Comment: I wonder why [the documentation for `ng generate interface`](https://angular.io/cli/generate#interface) doesn't mention this?

Comment: @ruakh I've also figured out that c stands for component and s stands for service. No documentation though

Answer (score 0):

The i stands for Interface in CLI.
When you need to create an interface automatically we use ng g(generate) i(interface) path_where_it_should_be_implemented.